# Setting a robocopy log file to a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, logging, set, robocopy

Robocopy is stalling when reading options `/Z /MIR` and `LOG+` from a variable.

```
ROBOCOPY %BACKUP_FAVS% %PATH_FAVS% %R_OPT%
```

Where `R_OPT= /Z /MIR /LOG+:%RLOG_Restore%` and is set by:

```
IF %ACTION%==Restore SET R_OPT=/Z /MIR /LOG+:%RLOG_Restore%
```

Where RLOG_Restore is set by:

```
SET RLOG_Restore=%BACKUP_FOLDER%\Robocopy_Log_Restore.txt
```

When the code executes, its stops at the robocopy line and does not continue on to the code after the robocopy line.  The robocopy line returns:

> Log File : H:\VDI_Backup\Robocopy_Log_Restore.txt

An `Echo` of the Robocopy results in:

```
ROBOCOPY  H:\VDI_Backup\Favorites  C:\user\Favorites /Z /MIR /LOG+:H:\VDI_Backup\Robocopy_Log_Restore.txt
```

I tried enclosing `/Z /MIR /LOG+:%RLOG_Restore%` in quotes resulting in invalid parameters error.  Where is this going wrong?

Comment: If you add `ECHO` in front of `ROBOCOPY %BACKUP_FAVS% %PATH_FAVS% %R_OPT%`, do you see the command line you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, it looks right to me.

Comment: Are you sure the files are not being copied? In my testing, the copy is working, but all of the results are going into the log file and not to the screen. so, you will only see "_Log File : H:\VDI_Backup\Robocopy_Log_Restore.txt_".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is access denied to the destination folder.
Nothing wrong with robocopy code.